Ubuntu Server cant Be Accessed Over IP But CloudFlare Tunnel Works Fine
I am having this strange issue, after running for sometime, my Ubuntu server cant be accessed over local IP, cant SSH, cant reach any service like radarr, Jellyfin or so, unless i restart it.
But i am using Cloudflare tunnel so that if i am out of my home, so i can reach it, and it works fine even when i cant access services locally.
Means I cant reach Jellyfin from local IP but I can reach it via Cloudflare tunnel and it works perfectly fine,, some goes with other services.
P.S. my server is over WiFi
